# How can I access inner class methods directly from other class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, interface, inner-classes

I have implemented two intefaces like this:

```
public OuterClass implements Interface1 {

    public InnerClass implements Interface2 {

    }
}
```

How can I access inner class methods directly from other classes in Java? Is it allowed in Java?

Comment: Please give more details: what did you try?

Comment: Of course. Most `Iterator`s are implemented as inner classes.

Comment: You have to make the inner class static to make use of the InnerClass from other classes other than OuterClass. Then you can use `OuterClass.Innerclass innerClass = new OuterClass.InnerClass();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a method in `InnerClass`, you need to have an instance of `InnerClass` to call a (non-static) method on it. So we add a simple method to your example...

```java
public class OuterClass implements Interface1 {
    
    public class InnerClass implements Interface2 {
        
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

... create an instance of `InnerClass` and call the method like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
    OuterClass.InnerClass inner = outer.new InnerClass();
    inner.method();
}
// output: hello
```

Since the inner class is not static, you need an instance of `OuterClass` to create the instance of `InnerClass` on which you can call your method.

If you make the inner class static, it is also possible to define static methods in `InnerClass`:

```java
public class OuterClass implements Interface1 {

    public static class InnerClass implements Interface2 {

        public void method() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }

        public static void staticMethod() {
            System.out.println("static");
        }
    }
}
```

In this scenario you don't need an instance of `OuterClass` to construct an instance of `InnerClass` as it is statically available and not bound to an instance. Additionally, you can call static methods of the inner class without an instance of the `InnerClass`:

```java
// call static method without any instance
OuterClass.InnerClass.staticMethod();

// create instance of inner class without instance of outer class
OuterClass.InnerClass inner = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
inner.method(); // call method of inner class

// output: static
           hello
```